# Curve modifier acting funky

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I want this object to follow this curve.

[image: objectandcurve]

On all the other meshes and curves, the curve modifier worked fine, but on this one, this happens.

[image: deformedmesh]

I've set the objects and the curves origin to the same place and I've applied scale to both of them as well.

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file https://blend-exchange.com/